# new Date object Javascript with 1 additional hour

Tags: javascript, date, fullcalendar, momentjs

I have a very strange behavior while extracting hours and minutes from a Date object. my initial object date is displaying 2017-01-16T19:00:00. here is the sample code:

```
var dt = new Date(date);
console.log("intial start date: "+date.format());
console.log("start date: "+dt);
```

but when I create a new Date object (dt) to extract hour and minute, I can see 1 more hour from the initial value....timezone seems to be correct....

here are the logs:

```
intial start date: 2017-01-16T19:00:00
start date: Mon Jan 16 2017 20:00:00 GMT+0100 (Romance Standard Time)
start date hours: 20 Minutes: 0
```

In fact I just want to extract hours and minutes from date, how can I do that with the correct hour and minutes ?

Comment: "timezone seems to be correct" — the timezone is different to the one you set in the ISO date.

Comment: But I do not specify any timezone in dt2 object...

Comment: You need to decide which hour you consider correct: the local hour, or the UTC hour.

Comment: @trincot — Which is the same as specifying local

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: What kind of object is the `date` variable?

Comment: I don't know exactly, this a parameter of a function (drop(date, allDay)  from full calendar)

Comment: @tiamat: All due respect, it's your responsibility to know what it is before asking others to help you with this. If you don't know, you find out -- as part of the process of basic research *before* posting a question.

Comment: you're right TJ. Crowder but I didn't know there was different "kind" of Date object. I searched before posting the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently you are using [fullCalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/), which uses [Moment](https://momentjs.com/) to handle dates. So when you call `.format()`, you call a method defined by Moment. The [documentation on that method](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) says:

> As of version 1.5.0, calling `moment#format` without a format will default to `moment.defaultFormat`. Out of the box, `moment.defaultFormat` is the ISO8601 format `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ`

So, by not specifying an argument to `.format()`, the date/time is rendered in the GMT 00:00 time zone, which is not yours. To solve this, provide a format argument, for example like this:

```
date.format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss')
```